# Asp:Treeview scroll node

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have searched this forum and other forums for help on how to scroll a given node (incl. selected node) into view, when the node is selected i code behind (C#). I have found several answers, but none of them works for me. And it seems, that many of the suggestions are old relating to older versions of asp:Treeview.

So my question is: What is the method of doing this for the current version of asp? I would prefer doing it from code behind (C#), where I populate the tree.

Thanks

hamej

Comment: What "current version of Asp"? Are you referring to .NET Core? Web Forms hasn't been updated in about a decade, so I am not sure what you mean specifically by "older versions", as it seems already like you are referring to something rather old in your question.

Comment: I am using Microsoft.net 4.7 and Webforms, which you says hasn't been changed for a long time. Anyway, I would appreciate, if you could say, how you would do it. The treeview is inside a View in a Multiview. Does that matter?